# How do I add an embedding layer in Keras starting from a pd dataframe?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a neural network using both categorical and numerical inputs using Keras to predict student grades ranging from 0-20.
My dataset is already split into train and test sets (two separate dataframes). I split the training set into numerical and categorical attributes. There are 17 categorical attributes and 16 numerical ones. Each categorical column only contains 3-4 categories so I have used OneHotEncoding to transform them. However, it creates unnecessary columns and I would like to experiment with embedding since it's more efficient.
I don't understand what I need to do in order to feed the categorical inputs into the neural model.

This is what my basic neural network looks like.

`input = keras.layers.Input(shape= 58,) #additional columns created through OHE`

`hidden1 = keras.layers.Dense(300, activation="relu")(input)`

`hidden2 = keras.layers.Dense(300, activation="relu")(hidden1)`

`concat = keras.layers.Concatenate()([input,hidden2])`

`output = keras.layers.Dense(21, activation = "softmax")(concat)  model = keras.Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[output])`

How can I expand it to include an embedding layer? Can I embed all the categorical columns together or would I need to add a layer for each?

I am using sparse categorical crossentropy as my loss function, but I guess I could use a different one now that the categorical inputs have been vectorized?

`model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3))`

I am very new to ML and NNs so apologies if my question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The word **'Embeddings'** is used in NLP parlance which means creating word vectors and the vectors which would be similar to each other would be having a similar meaning.

We use word embeddings for converting the text to numerical vectors before feeding it to the model.

One Hot Encoding is the correct choice when the variable is of nominal type.

For ordinal variables, you need to do Label Encoding.

So far the multi class classification is concerned in your problem, here is the code you can refer to get the concept cleared which uses Pandas and Keras High level API :

```
def get_category_encoding_layer(name, dataset, dtype, max_tokens=None):
# Create a layer that turns strings into integer indices.
  if dtype == 'string':
    index = layers.StringLookup(max_tokens=max_tokens)
# Otherwise, create a layer that turns integer values into integer indices.
  else:
    index = layers.IntegerLookup(max_tokens=max_tokens)
# Prepare a `tf.data.Dataset` that only yields the feature.
  feature_ds = dataset.map(lambda x, y: x[name])

# Learn the set of possible values and assign them a fixed integer index.
  index.adapt(feature_ds)

# Encode the integer indices.
  encoder = layers.CategoryEncoding(num_tokens=index.vocabulary_size())

# Apply multi-hot encoding to the indices. The lambda function captures the
# layer, so you can use them, or include them in the Keras Functional model later.
  return lambda feature: encoder(index(feature))
```

Here is the complete [gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/structured_data/preprocessing_layers.ipynb#scrollTo=GmgaeRjlDoUO) for your reference.